# query selecting alternating elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, selectors-api

I have the below HTML. I need to extract the text content into an array of maps like:

```js
[{key: 'keyone', value: 'valone'}, {key: 'keytwo', value: 'valtwo'}, ... ]
```

The only way I can think is two extract all the element using `document.querySelectorAll('ol *');` then to loop through each element and have some rule like if it is an odd number, add it as key with the following element as the value, then skip the next element. But this seems really hacky a brittle. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe using css selectors like `:nth-last-of-type(2)`?

```html
<ol>
  <dt>keyone</dt>
  <dd>valone</dd>
  <dt>keytwo</dt>
  <dd>valtwo</dd>
  ...
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming consistent pairs of `dt-dd` you could map the dt and use nextElementSibling to get the associated dd

```js
const dt = document.querySelectorAll( "ol dt" )

const res = [...dt].map(el => {
  return {key: el.textContent, value: el.nextElementSibling.textContent}
});

console.log( res );
```

```html
<ol>
  <dt>keyone</dt>
  <dd>valone</dd>
  <dt>keytwo</dt>
  <dd>valtwo</dd>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select all elements and then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the desired result

```js
const allNestedElements = [...document.querySelectorAll( "ol > *" )]
const result = allNestedElements.reduce( ( acc, curr, i ) => {
    if(i % 2) acc[acc.length - 1].value = curr.textContent;
    else acc.push({ key: curr.textContent })
    return acc;
}, [] );
console.log( result );
```

```html
<ol>
  <dt>keyone</dt>
  <dd>valone</dd>
  <dt>keytwo</dt>
  <dd>valtwo</dd>
</ol>
```